# How to add new css file for custom theme in Magento2

Tags: magento2, css

I have to add new css file for custom theme in magento 2. will anyone please tell me how to add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the below steps

1. Extend your **default_head_blocks.xml** at `app\design\frontend\Packagename\Themename\Magento_Theme\layout\default_head_blocks.xml` and place

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
       <head>
           <css src="css/custom.css" />
       </head>
   </page>
   ```
2. Add the CSS file at this path: `app\design\frontend\Packagename\Themename\web\css\custom.css`
3. And do a static deploy

   ```
   php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
   ```

Comment: there is no layout folder in \app\design\frontend\Packagename\Themename\Magento_Theme\

Comment: you need to create

Comment: ok thanks.. its working now. now i can add custom css. Thanks you so much Shyam and Manoj.

Comment: I am on magento 2.2.3 and it is not working for me...